# Access dataGrid information from another user control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls

I have two user controls setup on a Form.cs. Trying to create a modern UI. The first user control (database.cs) loads the database onto a dataGridView. The user can then edit the DB using this user control (database.cs) file. Now I want to be able to also access the dataGridView also from the second user control (scan.cs).

**The form1.cs code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static string db_n;
    public static string db_p;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userdata = WelcomeForm.Run();
        if (userdata != null)
        {
            db_n = userdata.UserName;
            db_p = userdata.UserSurname;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        scan1.BringToFront();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        database1.BringToFront();
    }
  }
}
```

**The database.cs code:**

```
public partial class Database : UserControl
{
    
    public Database()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void load_db_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id='" + Form1.db_n + "';database=db;password='" + Form1.db_p + "'"))
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table_new", 
                    connection);
                    adapter.Fill(table);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would I then access the dataGridView1 in scan.cs?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to access the control from another usercontrol? If so, you can refer to the following demo.

First, we can get the datagridview instance via `Property`.

Form1.cs

```
public Form1 f1;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Get the instance of this form
    f1 = this;
}

public DataGridView dataGridView { get; set; }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UCdatabase uCdatabase = new UCdatabase();
    uCdatabase.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    UCscan UCscan = new UCscan(f1);
    UCscan.Location = new Point(310, 0);
    // Save the DGV instance to dataGridView 
    dataGridView = uCdatabase.DGV;

    Controls.Add(uCdatabase);
    Controls.Add(UCscan);
}
```

UCdatabase.cs

```
public partial class UCdatabase : UserControl
{
    public UCdatabase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataGridView DGV 
    {
        get { return dataGridView1; }
    }
}
```

Then pass the datagridview instance to Ucscan by parameter that in constructor.

UCscan.cs

```
public partial class UCscan : UserControl
{
    public Form1 form1;

    public UCscan(Form1 f1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1 = f1;
    }

    private void btAccess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Access the DGV via "form1.dataGridView"
        label1.Text = form1.dataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

In this demo, we can get the first cell's value from datagridview.

Here is the test result.

[image]

Comment: @Sam If this answered your question, please [Upvote/Accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).